# Regex in Python to remove all uppercase characters before a colon

Tags: python, regex, string, text, python-re

I have a text where I would like to remove all uppercase consecutive characters up to a colon.  I have only figured out how to remove all characters up to the colon itself; which results in the current output shown below.

**Input Text**

```
text = 'ABC: This is a text. CDEFG: This is a second text. HIJK: This is a third text'
```

**Desired output:**

```
 'This is a text. This is a second text. This is a third text'
```

**Current code & output:**

```
re.sub(r'^.+[:]', '', text)

#current output
'This is a third text'
```

Can this be done with a one-liner regex or do I need to iterate through every `character.isupper()` and then implement regex ?

Comment: You can make use of ```+?``` or ```*?```(lazy regex) to find smallest matching string.

Comment: From desired output we can see that you remove consecutive uppercase letters, a colon, and at least one space. Could you please specify the objective more clearly

Comment: @MarkSouls But that would not solve the question, as in this case it does not match uppercase characters and the anchor prevents multiple matches

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yeah, I just put it as a kind of related tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[A-Z]+:\s*
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[A-Z]+:` Match 1+ uppercase chars A-Z and a `:`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTsflk/1)

```
import re

text = 'ABC: This is a text. CDEFG: This is a second text. HIJK: This is a third text'
print(re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]+:\s*', '', text))
```

Output

```
This is a text. This is a second text. This is a third text
```